# Linux, Octave & XML. The Java doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, xml, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to open an XML file using Octave (5.2.0) under Xubuntu.

The instructions: [XML cookbook](https://wiki.octave.org/Cookbook#Load_XML_files)

The problem:
javaaddpath doesn't work:

---

> error: javaMethod: /usr/local/lib/jvm/openjdk11/lib/server/libjvm.so: failed to load: /usr/local/lib/jvm/openjdk11/lib/server/libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> error: called from
> javaaddpath at line 52 column 13

---

A little digging indicates that `/usr/local/lib` does not contain a `jvm` directory

java -version results:

---

> openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)

---

lsb_release -a results:

---

> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
> Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
> Release: 18.04
> Codename:    bionic

---

Any suggestions as to what I have failed to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The standard path for an OpenJDK in Ubuntu is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-<version>-openjdk-<arch>/`

Comment: Does that indicate that it isn't looking for openjdk? Or should I install openjdk and change something else so that it uses openjdk. Openjdk isn't installed.

Comment: Still learning. >> version -java
ans = no Java available